# How to show / hide images at regular intervals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have following 4 bulbs:

```
<div id="bulb1" class="lightbulb"><img src=".\images\bulb.png" /></div>
<div id="bulb2" class="lightbulb"><img src=".\images\bulb.png" /></div>
<div id="bulb3" class="lightbulb"><img src=".\images\bulb.png" /></div>
<div id="bulb4" class="lightbulb"><img src=".\images\bulb.png" /></div>
```

My requirement is somewhat strange, but yes I have to do it...I have to do this in javascript.

I have an array which has 4 elements {1, 2, 3, 4}. Initially all bulbs(images) will be invisible.

First, I have to select on element from this array randomly. Suppose 2 is selected, then 2nd bulb will lighten up.

Then after 500 milliseconds, again my random function generator picks 4, then 4th bulb image is shown and 2nd is again invisible.

This I have to do 4 times in such a way that each time unique bulb gets lighten up. What approach and structure should I follow?

I am fused all the bulbs at beginning by calling this function

```
function hideBulbImages()
    {
        document.getElementById('bulb1').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('bulb2').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('bulb3').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('bulb4').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
```

I am thinking of the function `showBulbImage`...

I have written showBulbImage to show the bulb sequentially after every second like this

```
function showBulbImages()
    { 
        var blink_count = 0;
        var blink_the_bulbs = setInterval(function() {
            blink_count+=1;
            hideBulbImages();
            var blinking_bulb = "bulb" + blink_count;
            document.getElementById(blinking_bulb).style.visibility = "visible";
            if (blink_count > 4) 
            {
                 clearInterval(blink_the_bulbs);
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
```

Now I have to randomize the visibility of bulbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` and `Math.random()`

function `get_random_bulb()` gets a random number, hides visible image first and then shows random image.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
get_random_bulb();
function get_random_bulb() {
    var a = (parseInt(Math.random() * 4));
    $(".lightbulb img.block").removeClass("block").addClass("none");
    $(".lightbulb:eq(" + a + ") img").removeClass("none").addClass("block");
}
setInterval(function () {
    get_random_bulb();
}, 500);
```

});

```
<div id="bulb1" class="lightbulb">
    <img src=".\images\bulb.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div id="bulb2" class="lightbulb">
    <img src=".\images\bulb.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div id="bulb3" class="lightbulb">
    <img src=".\images\bulb.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div id="bulb4" class="lightbulb">
    <img src=".\images\bulb.png" class="none" />
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/v3HJG/3/)

Comment: can you give me full js code? not just functions but I need see how you are calling functions

Comment: actually I have a very big file in which I am implementing it. Let me tell you how my flow works? First of all I call hideBulbImages() in document.ready. Then I have a button say LightBulb on the click of which I call showBulbImages. Thats it. I have become successful in showing the bulb in sequential order after every second. The code I have posted and works fine. Now only I have to make it random. Also your var a = (parseInt(Math.random() * 4)); statement does not produce unique numbers and also produces 0 which I don't need. I need only from 1 to 4.

Comment: no it produces random number.
use this `var a = (parseInt(Math.random() * 4))+1;` to avoid 0.

Comment: yes it produces random numbers from 1 to 4. But those are not unique. It produces 3 two times. Sometimes 1 three times. If one number is generated, that should not again be generated.

Comment: you have to use while loop and calculate it. for examle, if current visible bulb number is 3, and random number is also 3, then generate another random number and check it again till u get unique number other than 3. got it??

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Hiral and some more googling I implemented my functionality. Below is my final `showBulbImage` function

```
function showBulbImages()
    { 
        var blink_count = 0;
        var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
        var randomArray = shuffleArray(myArray)
        var blink_the_bulbs = setInterval(function() {      
            var blinking_bulb = "bulb" + randomArray[blink_count];
            document.getElementById(blinking_bulb).style.visibility = "visible";
            blink_count+=1;
            if (blink_count > 3) 
            {
                 clearInterval(blink_the_bulbs);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function shuffleArray(array) 
    {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }
```